# Best framework for Unit-Testing some legacy ASP.NET 1.1 code

Tags: asp.net, unit-testing, legacy, .net-1.1

I have legacy asp.net 1.1 website.  It has a very poor VB layered achitecture.  Debugging takes about 10 minutes to run the credit card processing tests.

I'd like to add some unit testing capabilities to the solution to check my changes.

I was thinking about using mbunit with galleo.  Will mbunit and galleo work with my .net 1.1 code?  Any other recomendations for a unit testing framework thats compatible with .net 1.1 code?

### update

I'm not trying to test the actual asp.net portion of the code only new interfaces/business logic that I'm adding in the service/data layers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[nunit](http://nunit.org/) has a very complete suite of 1.1 compatible tools.

Comment: I've used NUnitAsp before. I've found it disappointing for unit testing. Lots of weirdness (like the IE COM control becoming disconnected during a test and causing an error, for example).

Comment: does it have its own test runner like galleo?  whats the name or it?  I've never used nunit.  I'm and mstest/mbunit guy

Comment: Up and running writing tests in about 20 minutes - thanks for that answer.